Manage Consumer to Partition Assignment in an uneven distributed topic
I have two microservices communicating with each other over Kafka. The producer microservice sends updates of different users to the Consumer microservice over a Kafka topic partitioned by a specific key, which is the city of that user.
I want all messages with that key to be processed using the same consumer process. The application has some in-memory state, which all the consumers do not share, and keeping this data in a centralized shared resource like a Database would significantly harm my response time.
The problem is that partitioning by this key results in an uneven distribution (cities have different populations, which causes different rates of update message production). One partition has more messages than all other partitions combined.
I can guarantee that a single consumer process can handle the partition with the most messages. Still, I also want to ensure that the partition with the second-most messages is not assigned to the same consumer process.
So far, I have had a single consumer process with considerable resources to handle all the incoming messages. Still, I want to scale my consumer application horizontally.
